# How to insert a file? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I want the code to do:
The user is able to insert his/her own textfile and the program counts the amount of letters/numbers (if I'm good enough pictures too).

The part of the inserting the users own file is my problem. Can someone explain to me how its possible or isn't it possible for python?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: I don't know what "insert" means in this context. Do you mean the user enters a file name? That could be done with the `input` function. This is basic enough that you would be well served running through some tutorials before going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking how to open a text file and prompt the user for an input in python. This is done using the open and input function.

```
filename = input("> ") #prompt user for input
file = open(filename, r) #open file
data = file.read() #transform file to a string
```

To count the number of letters and numbers:

```
print(len(data)) #count the length of the string
```

Comment: ...or asking how to prompt the user for input.